# How to get a substring from a found string to a character in C++?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

For example I have a string:

```
int random_int = 123; // let's pretend this integer could have various values!!

std::string str = "part1 Hello : part2 " + std::to_string(random_int) + " : part3 World ";
```

All parts are divided by the characters `:`

Let's say I want to find a substring from "part2" to the next character `:`, which would return `part2 123` in this case.

I know how to find the pos of "part2" by `str.find("part2")`, but I don't know how to determine the length to the next `:` from that "part2", because the length can be of various length.

For example, I know that part3 substring could be extracted with `str.substr(str.find("part3"));`, but only because it's at the end...

So, is there a subtle way to get the substring `part2 123` from that string?

Comment: `std::string::find` takes a position find in the string should start at as the second argument, so it seems you can find the first `:` and then do `str.find(':', previous_delimeter_position + 1)`

Comment: @fas Ah, this points me towards the right direction, but will that also work if the input is scattered like `std::string str = "part2 123 : part3 World : part1 Hello "` and I still want to return "part2 123" with the same code piece?

Comment: [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) coupled with [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) makes an easy general purpose tokenizer.